# How can I write data to file and access it from outside the app (without SD card)?

Tags: android, file-io, sd-card, streamwriter

I am pretty new to Android programming and writing my very first app for my Diploma Thesis.
Now I am all but finished but have one thing left that I couldn´t get an answer to anywhere on the net. So maybe someone here can help.

Part of what my app must do is write results from previous operations to a freely accessible file for later analysis. 
So what I got so far is that I am able to write a file to SD card with the following code:

```
String packageName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/Android/data/" + packageName + "/files/";
if (isExternalStorageAvailable() && isExternalStorageWritable()) 
{
    String filename = "_results.dat";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists) 
    {
         new File(path).mkdirs();
    }
    // Open output stream
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(path + filename,true);

    fOut.write("lalala".getBytes());
        etc.
     }

public static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() 
{ 
    // Retrieving the external storage state
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    // Check if available
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
 }


public static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() 
{       
    // Retrieving the external storage state
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    // Check if writable
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) 
    {
      return true;
    }

    return false;

 }
```

That file I can later access, copy, whatever. Like I want it to be. Now the actual question is:

Is there a way to achieve this without an SD card in the phone? Or can I only write into 'app-memory' (which wouldn´t suffice my needs)?
I only ask because as of yet there are no SD cards in the phones where I am going to deploy the app. And we have to decide if we have to 'upgrade' the devices :).

Comment: SD cards or other external storages are pretty common to android phones. Without knowing it for sure I would say, that 90% of all Android phones have an external storage.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to avoid having them upgrade the phone with an SD card, check out [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) link. It SAYS that files written to internal storage are not accessible by other apps, but if you read on, you can set other flags:

> MODE_PRIVATE will create the file (or replace a file of the same name)
>   and make it private to your application. Other modes available are:
>   MODE_APPEND, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE.